# Disabling user from turning toggling airplane mode

Tags: android

I don't know whether this can be done but, I want my app to toggle airplane mode on/off. Ok that's simple. But on toggling it off, the user should not be able to toggle it on by going into android settings. This should be disabled. Only the app should be able to revert the changes back. Or atleast till the app is closed. 
Any idea ?

Comment: may I ask why would you need this? there may be easier ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: actually its part of a project ,kind of like a parental control tool. Basically , when the phone enters into a  certain location (will be got from GPS) , the phone should goto flight mode.For example, When a phone enters a college campus, flight mode must activate.  This change should be strict, because if the user is able to goto settings and turn it off, it wouldnt make much sense. Cant really think of any other way

Comment: I don't think this is possible and doesn't really sound like a good idea. Maybe you could save the state in a preference and when the user returns check the current state of Airplane mode and change it to what is stored in the preference

Comment: @codeMagic 
hmm yea felt the same way. Will look for a few more replies and then maybe decide on abandoning the idea.

Answer (score 0):

> I want my app to toggle airplane mode on/off.

Note that this is no longer possible as of Android 4.2.

> But on toggling it off, the user should not be able to toggle it on by going into android settings.

Download the source code to Android, make your desired changes, compile your revised OS and pour it into a ROM mod, and install that ROM mod on whatever Android devices you can.

IOW, you cannot do this from an SDK app.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that toggling airplane mode on/off is no longer possible as of Android 4.2 (Jelly Bean major release 1). Check out this link [Android 4.2](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html) for more info.